# Executing a shell script from a file

Tags: shell, sh, sunos

My OS platform is this : SunOS machinehull01 5.10 Generic_148888-05 sun4v sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200

I have written a shell script to run from a file

File name: test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
VARNAME=$grep '-l' TestWord /home/hull/xml/text/*.txt
echo "Found $VARNAME"
```

When I run the above command in the console I'm getting the correct output without errors, But when I run **sh test.sh** or **./test.sh** I'm getting below error

```
test.sh: -l: not found
Found
```

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

```
#!/bin/sh
VARNAME=`grep -l TestWord /home/hull/xml/text/*.txt`
echo "Found $VARNAME"
```

I had to put those (**`**)there.

Comment: This is the same answer that `hek2mgl` provided (backticks are an older version of `$(...)`, and should't be used in new code).

Comment: yeah but his solution is not working in Solaris, but this does.

Comment: Oh, right, Solaris uses a non-POSIX shell (the actual Bourne shell, I think) for `/bin/sh`. You might consider switching to Solaris's POSIX shell, `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You are searching for so called "command substitution" :

```
VARNAME=$(grep -l TestWord /home/hull/xml/text/*.txt)
echo "Found $VARNAME"
```

It will execute the command between `$(` and  the closing parenthesis `)` in a subshell and return the output of the command into `VARNAME`.

Comment: I'm getting below error when I added brackets there test.sh: syntax error at line 2: `WEEKLY=$' unexpected